# cannot style nested div with radium

Tags: reactjs, radium

I currently have a nested div which currently contains a react component called `react-mobile-picker`. Unfortunately there is no styling option to style it, see link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mobile-picker

Therefore, i have installed radium which supposedly allows you to style nested items.

I want to style the picker with a specific font. I have tried it in chrome, and the  i need to target is called 'picker-container'.

The code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';
import Picker from 'react-mobile-picker';

class Movement extends Component {
  render() {
    ...
    const style = {
      picker: {
        zIndex: 0,
        paddingTop: '10px',
        position: 'relative',
        ':picker-container': {
          zoom: 10,
          fontFamily: 'serif',
        },
      },
    };
    return (
      <div style={style.picker}>
        <Picker
          optionGroups={zone}
          valueGroups={valueGroups}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Radium(Movement);
```

I can see the above style being applied (styles.picker), but the child style is not being applied (picker-container).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to style a nested element with `radium` by it's element's `class` (or any other css selector) you should use the [`radium <Style />`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/api#style-component) component and pass that selector as the `scopeSelector` prop.

In your case you can use it as follows:

```
import Radium, {Style} from 'radium';

...

// remove the ':picker-container' key from the style object -
// that's not where it should be styled

 const style = {
  picker: {
    zIndex: 0,
    paddingTop: '10px',
    position: 'relative',
  },
};

...

// pass the '.picker-container' styles as rules to the <Style /> component

   <div style={style.picker}>
   <Style scopeSelector=".picker-container" rules={{ zoom: 10,fontFamily: 'serif'}} />
        <Picker
          optionGroups={zone}
          valueGroups={valueGroups}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
  </div>
```